# Receiver view is not created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I first check whether message is sent or received then it create viewHolder accordingly for sender and receiver

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
Context context;
ArrayList<Message> Messages;
final int ITEM_SENT=1;
final int ITEM_RECEiVE=2;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    this.context = context;
    Messages = messages;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType==ITEM_SENT){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_send,parent,false);
        return new SenderViewHolder(view);
    }
    else {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_receive,parent,false);
        return new ReceiverViewHolder(view);
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message= Messages.get(position);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equals(message.getSenderId()))
        return ITEM_SENT;
    else {
        return ITEM_RECEiVE;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message=Messages.get(position);
        if (holder.getClass() == SenderViewHolder.class) {
            SenderViewHolder viewHolder = (SenderViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.send_message.setText(message.getMessage());
        } else {
            ReceiverViewHolder viewHolder = (ReceiverViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.receive_message.setText(message.getMessage());
        }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Messages.size();
}

public class SenderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView send_message;
    private ImageView feeling;
    public SenderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        send_message=itemView.findViewById(R.id.send_message);
        feeling=itemView.findViewById(R.id.feeling);
    }
}

public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView receive_message;
    private ImageView feeling;
    public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        receive_message=itemView.findViewById(R.id.receive_message);
        feeling=itemView.findViewById(R.id.feeling);
    }
}
```

}

Then i create a chat node where i store the sender and receiver message and use snapshot to fetch the data from database and store it in an arraylist after executing its shows the message of sender but didn't show the message of receiver.

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MessageAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Message> messages;
String senderRoom,receiverRoom;
EditText chatBox;
FloatingActionButton chatSendBtn;
FirebaseDatabase database;
RecyclerView chatView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    chatBox=findViewById(R.id.chatBox);
    chatSendBtn=findViewById(R.id.chatSendBtn);
    chatView=findViewById(R.id.chatView);
    messages=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter=new MessageAdapter(this,messages);
    chatView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    chatView.setAdapter(adapter);
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String receiverUid=getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
    final String senderUid= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    senderRoom=senderUid+receiverUid;
    receiverRoom=receiverRoom+senderUid;
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    database.getReference().child("chats")
            .child(senderRoom)
            .child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    messages.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Message message = snapshot1.getValue(Message.class);
                        message.setMessageId(snapshot1.getKey());
                        messages.add(message);
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });



    chatSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String messageTxt = chatBox.getText().toString();

            Date date = new Date();
            final Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
            chatBox.setText("");
            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .push()
                    .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            database.getReference().child("chats")
                                    .child(receiverRoom)
                                    .child("messages")
                                    .push()
                                    .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Have you checked using log that is you if else running properly in OnCreateViewHolder()

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the adapter:

```
adapter.setItems(messages);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```